# Compare Time In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I need to be able to compare time in my rails app. Basically I have to compare my created_at timestamp and if the time in the timestamp is greater than say 10 AM then have to highlight the record as red in color in my view. How can i compare time to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try anything? A google search for your title shows LOTS of resources for this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def css_class(record)
  today_ten_am = Time.now.at_beginning_of_day.advance(hours: 10)
  if record.created_at > today_ten_am
    'danger'
  end
end
```

For the future: please post more inputs, what you tried, your existing code and everything.